# R gputools: clearing or reusing memory

Tags: r, memory

I'm running a simulation using the `gputools` package and I want to make sure I don't run in to memory problems as the simulation progresses. Does `gputools` automatically clear the GPU memory?

I checked the `gputools` documentation [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/gputools.pdf) but I don't see any mention of how memory is handled.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, all the functions in `gputools` are just wrappers around lower level functions provided by `BLAS` and the `NVIDIA CUDA toolkit`.

I've briefly dug into the toolkit, and they do provide memory allocation and freeing functions for `C/C++` users, but calling those from `R` would be highly impractical, so i think it's fairly safe to say that the allocation and freeing of memory is handled by the lower level functions that `gputools` wraps around.